# How to customize the login message on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: login

How to customize the login message on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

I want to customize the below login message.Please let me know which file do I need to edit.

```
root@10.1.235.227's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-25-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Wed Oct 14 01:05:33 CDT 2015

  System load:    0.0             Processes:           117
  Usage of /home: 0.1% of 944MB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage:   4%              IP address for eth0: 10.1.235.227
  Swap usage:     0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


Last login: Wed Oct 14 01:05:35 2015 from 172.20.20.98
```

Answer (score 25):

To customize the pre-login message, such as to create a login banner, you need to edit `/etc/issue` file.

To customize post-login messages, you can edit some of the files in `/etc/update-motd.d`. Such files as `00-header` and `10-help-text` in that directory are safe to edit.

Another possibility is to add a custom function/command to your `.bashrc`  at the end of the file.

For instance, I have the following function defined at the top of my `.mkshrc` file :

```bsh
 testTTY(){

  isTTY=$(tty | awk '{if ($0~/\/dev\/tty.*/) {print "true"}else{print "false"}}')

  if [ "$isTTY" = "true" ]; then
    printf "You are in virtual console\n"
    printf "current disk usage is"
    df
  fi
}
```

And I call the function at the end of `.bashrc` with just `testTTY`. As you can see from the code, the function determines if I logged in into TTY or not, and if it is TTY, it shows appropriate message and output of `df`command

Answer (score 4):

The configuration files are in `/etc/update-motd.d`. `motd` stands for the *message of the day*.

Comment: Hello I want to remove these lines from login prompt and make my own customized message

Comment: Try to change the files and see what happens. For instance add a line 'printf "My custom message"' at the end of 00-header file. Take a look at printf lines and change them as you wish.