# How can I distinguish a terminal window (GUI) from a console (CTRL+ALT+F3)?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, virtual-console

I use a coloured bash prompt like so:

```
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
reset=$(tput sgr0)
bold=$(tput bold)
export PS1='($?) \[$bold$blue\]\u@\h:\w\[$reset\]$(__git_ps1)> '
```

I usually work in a terminal window (gnome-terminal) but sometimes in a full-screen console (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>).

My coloured prompt is fine in the GUI terminal but hard to read in full-screen because the colours look different. So I'd like to use a different colour (e.g. `cyan=$(tput setaf 6)`), when in console window. For this to work I need to figure out which *mode* I'm currently in and set my `$PS1` accordingly.

I tried the `tty` command. It gives

```
/dev/pts/0  # GUI terminal
/dev/tty3   # console
```

I also tried to examine the value of `$TERM`. It gives

```
xterm-256color  # GUI terminal
linux           # console
```

Both of them would work for me but my question is: **Is that the correct way to reliably distinguish console vs. terminal or are there better ways?** I'm on 17.10.1 if that matters.

Comment: "Correct" depends on what the most important characteristic is.  It appears that it is "is this Linux virtual terminal or not", and then $TERM is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of ways to determine that, three famous being:

- `tty` - print the file name of the terminal connected to standard input:

  ```bsh
  /dev/pts/10
  /dev/tty1
  ```

  [This function](https://askubuntu.com/a/685300/507051) written by Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy makes use of `tty`.
- `ps hotty $$` (short for `ps --no-header --format tty --pid $$`):

  ```bsh
  pts/10
  tty1
  ```
- `who who whom | awk '{ print $2 }'` (in fact that's `who` with [two arbitrary arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377507/246819), equal to `who -m` – which also matches the pun):

  ```bsh
  pts/10
  tty1
  ```

I suspect the values of `TERM` to differ between distributions and even releases, but `tty` is a stable and reliable way. I would use it like so:

```bsh
if tty|grep -q tty; then
  echo "That's a TTY."
else
  echo "That's not a TTY."
fi
```

There seems to be a problem with at least `who` in `gnome-terminal`, luckily there's a [wrapper script](https://github.com/ConradHughes/utmpwrap) to work around this issue.

Helpful links:

- [How to check which tty am I using](https://askubuntu.com/q/902998/507051)
- [How to get the tty in which bash is running? · Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/270272/246819)
- [Bash Prompt HOWTO: Checking the Current TTY](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x721.html)